# appending or merging two or more list

Tags: python

I have these lists.

```
l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
l2 = [6,7,8,9,0]
l3 = [11,12,13,14,15]
```

And my desired output is like this.

```
[[1,6,11], [2,7,12], [3,8,13], [4,9,14], [5,0,15]]
```

What I have tried is only like this.

```
[[x] for x in l1]
```

I don't have any idea how to append the second and third list.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're ok with `tuples`, use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) like below:

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [6,7,8,9,0]
>>> l3 = [11,12,13,14,15]
>>> 
>>> zip(l1, l2, l3)
[(1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12), (3, 8, 13), (4, 9, 14), (5, 0, 15)]
```

Or you can create lists of lists, again using [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

```
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
[[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 0, 15]]
```

Be sure to understand that the lengths of the zipped lists *must be equal*, or in your case, you might end up missing some data. This is stated in the docs:

> The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence

Example of the above, notice how we're missing the last list.

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [list(x) for x in zip(l1, l2, l3)]
[[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14]]
```

You can get around that by using [`itertools.izip_longest()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) which allows a *fillvalue* to be used (defaults to `None`):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> [list(x) for x in izip_longest(l1, l2, l3)]
[[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [None, 0, 15]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [6,7,8,9,0]
>>> l3 = [11,12,13,14,15]
>>> 
>>> zip(l1, l2, l3)
[(1, 6, 11), (2, 7, 12), (3, 8, 13), (4, 9, 14), (5, 0, 15)]
>>> 
>>> map(list, zip(l1, l2, l3))
[[1, 6, 11], [2, 7, 12], [3, 8, 13], [4, 9, 14], [5, 0, 15]]
```